# Identifying cause of RDS Outage

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, rds

I have one RDS MySQL database ! Experienced an outage by 14:36pm today where the CPU utilization was 99.7% and the no. of connections was 150. Is there any way I can find out what caused the outage ?

[image]

Comment: Slow query log might give some indication of what is going on, if you have it enabled. But why do you not have some monitoring inside your application to let you know what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

- If you are connecting to the RDS using a web server like apache2 then I would suggest checking the apache2 logs to find the source of connection requests
- The analytics on your web page also gives the detail information about the source of traffic
- Most commonly the code is not closing the MYSQL connection once the task is done.Check the code.